# Test support library in android studio is not compiled

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, android-testing

I have the latest support library installed in my SDK.
gradle file

```
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.win.dat_2"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }


        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies { 
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) 
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espres‌​so-core:2.2.2', { 
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations' }) 
    }
```

Comment: dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
}

Comment: What errors does your LogCat show when you try to build your projects? Also, please paste your entire `gradle` file. You'd want to also add the dependencies portion to the post and not as a comment.

Comment: Can you update gradle file ?

Comment: sorry for the late:

Comment: Error: Failed to resolve:com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In app gradle add this to defaultConfig

multiDexEnabled = true